# Virtualbox не видит usb устройства

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, usb

прочитал все мануалы и форумы какие нашел по сабжу, поставил плагин для USB2.0.
Поставил virtualbox-guest-additions
Добавил фильтр для устройства.но когда Запускаю машину 
в выводе lsusb вижу только:

```
хаб 2.0
хаб виртуалбокс
хаб 1.1
```

менюшка devices говорит мне что нужное устройство захвачено. тогда где оно ?
tail /dev/input/js0 ничего не выводит (устройство это джойстик)
собственно не видит никаких usb устройств вообще, пробовал хаб, флешки.

хост система windows

Comment: А `Extension Pack` в хостовую тачку воткнул?

Comment: да воткнул Extension Pack

Comment: Virtualbox v5.1.28? и какая именно винда?

Comment: vbox последний(ставил пару дней назад) , винда 7

Comment: Есть возможность перенести виртуалку на другой хост и\или с другой ос?